# How to get Directory Access type in C#?

Tags: c#, permissions

I have to get Directory Access permission in C#. Is there any property in C# to get Directory access type?

Answer (score 2):

Check here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1h6d4k4.aspx

and if that's not what you want then check here and you may find the relevant properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_properties.aspx